# how to add objects to facebook open graph object browser

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently creating a facebook canvas app using facebook javascript sdk but i can't seem to add app-owned objects, the closest answer i get is from this tutorial:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#creating

but i do not know how to use "curl" and is it possible to do it with javascript sdk?

it seems that the documentation on facebook is lacking on this part

Answer (score 1):

`Curl` is how you do an HTTP POST with PHP. If you want to do the same in plain JavaScript, then you have to mock an HTML form submit. But it is very easy if you use `jQuery` instead.

For example, if you want to do the same which the following curl command is doing;

```
curl
  -X POST
  "https://graph.facebook.com/me/books.reads"
  -F "book=505124632884107"
  -F "access_token=1234567890"
```

You just need to call the following with jQuery:

```
$.post( "https://graph.facebook.com/me/books.reads", { book: "505124632884107", access_token: "1234567890" } );
```

Disclaimer: I really do not know what is available in Facebook JavaScript SDK. I just pointed out how you'd go about mimicking PHP Curl using JavaScript (jQuery).